# How to insert chemical names instead of structures in a chemical scheme?

Tags: symbols, chemfig, text

I'd like to make a chemical scheme in a document I'm writing. However, the code I am trying to compile gives some errors. The error occurs at the line 11 (line after arrow command, with `\chemname`).

I think this might also have to do with the text I'm trying to insert. Can I just insert text instead of a `\chemname{\chemfig{}}{}` or can I use something like the following code: `\chemname{}{Glucose oxidase-FAD}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemname
{\chemfig{*6((<:OH)-(<OH)-(<:OH)-(<OH)-O-(>-OH)}}
{\beta -D-glucose}
\+
Glucose oxidase-FAD
\arrow{<=>}
\chemname
{\chemfig{*6((<:OH)-(<OH)-(<:OH)-(=O)-O-(>-OH)}}
{\delta -D-gluconolactone}
\+
Glucose oxidase-$\text{FADH}_2$
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Thanks for helping out a rookie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

- the `\chemfig` formulae are both missing a closing `)` to end the ring.
- `\beta` and `\delta` must be placed in math mode.
- `\text` is undefined; you need to load `amsmath` or `amstext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{*6((<:OH)-(<OH)-(<:OH)-(<OH)-O-(>-OH))}}
    {$\beta$-D-glucose}
  \+
  Glucose oxidase-FAD
  \arrow{<=>}
  \chemname
    {\chemfig{*6((<:OH)-(<OH)-(<:OH)-(=O)-O-(>-OH))}}
    {$\delta$-D-gluconolactone}
  \+
  Glucose oxidase-$\text{FADH}_2$
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

---

Possible further improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  greek   = textgreek
}

\usepackage{showframe}% show page dimensions

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \setatomsep{2.2em}%
  \schemestart[-90]
    \chemname
      {\chemfig{*6((<:HO)-(<OH)-(<:OH)-(<OH)-O-(>-HO))}}
      {\iupac{\b-\D-glucose}}
    \+
    \iupac{Glucose oxidase-FAD}
    \arrow{<=>}
    \chemname
      {\chemfig{*6((<:HO)-(<OH)-(<:OH)-(=O)-O-(>-HO))}}
      {\iupac{\d-\D-gluconolactone}}
    \+
    \iupac{Glucose oxidase-FADH$_2$}
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I indeed forgot to include `amsmath` in the MWE, but it is included in the LaTeX code I'm using. I also tried putting `\beta` and `\gamma` in math mode, but in trying to solve my problem I must have taken them out. I indeed believe the issue was the `)` I forgot to add. Thanks! One litte thing left: Is there a quick way to fit the scheme to the `\textwidth`?

Comment: @HenryO. see my updated answer